# How to build whl package for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-wheel

Hi I have a built up Python 2.7 environment with Ubuntu 19.10.

I would like to build a whl package for pandas.

I pip installed the pandas but do not know how to pack it into whl package.

May I ask what I should do to pack it.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot pack back an installed wheel. Either you download a ready-made wheel or build from sources. `pip download` or `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

Comment: @phd Thanks mate I did it with python setup.py bdist_wheel. Would you like to post your answer and I'll accept it~ lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pack back an installed wheel. Either you download a ready-made wheel with `pip download` or build from sources: `python setup.py bdist_wheel` (need to download the sources first).